# Why can't VLOOKUP function right-to-left?

Tags: excel-formula, logic

I know you can use INDEX/MATCH to do this, but is there a logical or specific reason why VLOOKUP cannot do this?

Maybe only Microsoft knows, but it seems simple enough that if it could have been done, it would have.

EDIT: to clarify, note the following formulas for the difference I am explaining.

=VLOOKUP(A1,A:C,3,false) - valid
=VLOOKUP(C1,C:A,3,false) - not valid

Comment: I don't think Excel could make sense of a range like `C:A` in any context, could it? A range is always left to right. So for the kind of lookup you seek, the syntax would probably have to be something like `vlookup(<value>, <range>, <lookup col index>, <return col index>, <exact>)` e.g. `vlookup(c1,a:c,3,1,false)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually it is possible to do a right to left vlookup but you need to redifne your array. like this:

```
(A)      (B)    (C)
0,457   3,55    500
0,525   3,25    400
0,616   2,93    300
0,675   2,75    250
0,746   2,57    200
0,835   2,38    150
0,946   2,17    100
1,09    1,95    50
1,29    1,71    0
```

so here is a formula which fetches A1 when asked to lookup C1 in the array of A:A, C:C.

```
=VLOOKUP(C1;CHOOSE({2\1};A:A;C:C);2;FALSE)
```

Basically you need to redefine your lookup array, so I go for a 'choose' formula which
sets up a table array where Column 1 is C:C and Column 2 is A:A.
Then vLookup formula looks up the lookup_Value from C:C which is column 1 of the Table array and then locates 500 in C1 and then accordingly goes to A:A (column 2 of the table array) and pulls out the corresponding value from A1 which is 0,457.

P.S. **depending on your country coding system, you need to replace all ";" with "," and "\" with ",".** 

You may download [this file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wmpc2ckywaxg0mk/vlookup.xlsx?dl=0) and open it in your excel and see how your excel translates these ";" "\" into your country coding system.