# Excel - VLOOKUP to return each result in an array, not just the first

Tags: arrays, excel, vlookup

I am currently working between two workbooks.

In **Workbook A** I have the following data.

```
       A  ...   D        E        F  ...   N
1.| ID     |  Name  |  Desc  |  Prod  | Country|
2.| 12345  |   Apple|   Fruit|      10|      US|
3.| 12346  |  Celery|     Veg|     150|      US|
4.| 12347  |    Mint|    Herb|      25|      FR|
```

I have been using the following formula from [AHC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069409/why-cant-vlookup-function-right-to-left) in **Workbook B**, the aim is to perform a VLOOKUP which grabs all the **ID's** but only if the **Country** = "US".

```
=VLOOKUP("US", CHOOSE({2,1},Workbook A.xlsx!Table1[ID], Workbook A.xlsx!Table1[Country]), 2, FALSE)
```

This formula works well, however, my problem comes because the formula will only ever return the first instance in the array. For example, if I include this formula in **Workbook B, Col A** it will look like this:

```
       A  
1.|ID of US| 
2.| 12345  | 
3.| 12345  | 
4.| 12345  |
5.| 12345  |
6.| 12345  |
7.| 12345  |
```

How would I make this formula work so that it returns each **ID** which matches "US", not just the first occurrence of a match?

Comment: Quick questions, what is the layout of your Workbook B?  Do you list out all the ID's on one column and have a result on the next?  Or do you just want a formula to drag down to show any ID that matches the condition `(Country = "US")`?  And also, is it possible a duplicate ID be used from Workbook A and you want to show twice on Workbook B?

Answer (score 0):

In **B2** put this formula: 
*You might need to adjust the rows of the ranges (I went till 100).*

```
={ISERROR(INDEX(D$2:D$100,SMALL(IF(N$2:N$100=$A2,ROW(D1)),ROW(N1))),"")}
```

**NOTE:** 
Step 1) Insert the formula **only** in Cell **B2** **without** the **{}** 
Step 2) Once the formula is inserted mark the entire formula and press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> so the formula will get the **{}** 
Step 3) Drag it down the rows as far as you need it to get the list.

Comment: I don't think this solution works. When I use the formula it just returns "TRUE" into B2. This doesn't resolve my issue.